# Did I break my DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor, short-circuit

I have a 90 V, 1/4 HP, 165 RPM Dayton 2h573 dc motor with 125DV-C driver.

I wanted to adjust max voltage on the driver and accidentally shorted the leads while the motor was running (i left multimeter leads in current measurement mode).

Driver burned for sure and I got a new one but motor does not run anymore. Wondering if i damaged it?

1. I test both leads and getting 3.5 Ohms  (Not sure what it should be for this motor)
2. I tested each lead to ground and its open (Both wire and motor casing)
3. New driver without load (motor disconnected) i get about 80 volts
4. After i connect the motor, voltage drops to 3.5 volts
5. Potentiometer is ok. I tested resistance and it goes 0-5ohms

Anything else i can do to verify my motor?

Comment: It seems unlikely that a DC motor would be damaged by shorting the leads unless the driver damaged it when the short was removed.  I would remove the brushes and take a look to see if they look as if they are damaged.

Comment: Thank you John,I check the brushes and they seem fine. everything seems soldered in place.  I did another test just now.. i measured R while manually spinning the shaft. Multimeter goes to 0.00 while i spin it slowly and then goes up to ~3.5 when i stop. I could not find a dead spot (short in the windings) but my understanding is that R should stay about same as constant if motor is good?

Comment: Hi Larry!  You can't really measure resistance with an ohmmeter because when you turn the shaft you are generating a voltage.  Try these tests.  First make sure you have a connection between the leads and the brush contacts.  Then re-install the brushes.  If you can turn the shaft, it should be harder to turn when the leads are shorted together.  Finally, try applying a small amount of current and turning the shaft.  If it jumps or starts to spin but won't re-start, you might have a bad rotor winding.  Good luck!

Comment: John. Thanks for your support. I have some progress. It seems i also had an issue with potentiometer lead (re-soldered) and now the motor runs sort off. It starts on its own when i increase the potentiometer but has a very jerky motion. I measured Volts on ARM leads and its 60Volt (for this 90-volt motor). AC input is 123V so no issues there. I am guessing two possibilities: 1.  As you said, I have a short on one of the windings or 2. The controller has issues and its max output Voltage of 60V is not enough. I tried to get volts to 90v on controller maxing everything but I can't get it to max.